# Where the scan copy is stored and maximum how much time it can be alive if I do Elastic Search with scroll and scan

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have some questions in Elastic Search with search type scan.

1. Where the scan copy is stored and maximum how much time it can be alive if I do  Elastic Search with scroll and scan. I can give scroll=60m, but don't know maximum how much time I can give.

Answer (score 0):

[scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html) and [scan](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-type.html#scan) are two different feature of elasticsearch.

According to documentation.

1. [scan](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-type.html#scan) is search type that disables sorting and scoring.
2. [scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html) API can be used to retrieve large numbers of results (or even all results) from a single search request, in much the same way as you would use a cursor on a traditional database.

so, scroll API initial search request you have to tell, how long you would like to have “[search context alive](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html#scroll-search-context)”  (see Keeping the search context alive), eg ?scroll=1m.

so answers to your question is elastic search do not store any scan copy separately. however, search scroll API open search context prevents the old segments from being deleted while they are still in use, that is how scroll API return the results of the initial search request, regardless of subsequent changes to documents.

Read the document to find out more about “[search context alive](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html#scroll-search-context)”.

and yes you can keep “[search context alive](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html#scroll-search-context)” as long as you would like.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, still I have doubt that if I give ?scroll=12h, It should be alive for 12 hours and in that long time where the search result are stored? Because document says that once I made the request with scroll option, I will get the same result when I made the first call(I mean changes happened after the request will not reflect in result). So will this store in some memory for reference is my question.

Comment: please read documentation "Keeping Search Context Alive" section. it clearly says that how elastic search preserve the scroll and return the result of initial search. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html#scroll-search-context